# Sqlmap inline parameters

Tags: sql, cakephp, sqlmap

Hi ive just hear about an error in cakephp that allows sql inyection;
https://twitter.com/cakephp/status/328610604778651649

I was trying to test my site using sqlmap, but i cant find how to specify the params.

The url i am testing is;

```
http://127.0.0.1/categories/index/page:1/sort:id/direction:asc
```

And the parameters i want to sqlmap inyect are in the url (page:,sort:,direction:)

I have try to run;

```
python sqlmap.py -u "http://127.0.0.1/categories/index/page:1/sort:id/direction:asc"
```

But nothing...
Any clue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CakePHP there are [passed arguments](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passed-arguments), [named parameters](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#named-parameters), and [querystring parameters](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-querystring-parameters).

Passed arguments look like `.../index/arg` are accessed with `$this->request->pass[0]`, where '0' is the array index. Named parameters look like `.../index/key:value` and are accessed with `$this->request->named['key']`. Querystring parameters look like ̀.../index?key=value`and are accessed with`$this->request->query['key']`.

Your URL uses named parameters so it should look like this (without the question mark):

```
http://127.0.0.1/categories/index/page:1/sort:id/direction:asc
```

**Edit:**

Since CakePHP uses mod_rewrite, you have to specify the parameters as explained in the [sqlmap wiki](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/FAQ#how-to-use-sqlmap-with-mod_rewrite-enabled).

Comment: this doesnt answer my question, my question was how usage sqlmap ( sqlmap.org ) with cakephp

Comment: Thanks! the edit did answer my question!, im gonna try with 
`python sqlmap.py -u "http://127.0.0.1/categories/index/page:*/sort:*/direction:*"`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I misunderstood the original question.